How to I use pyopenvdb when using a bpy-build
I built blender as a python module, which worked out great (using make bpy). The problem is, that pyopenvdb is not built as well. Is there a possibility to do this from build options? I checked that WITH_OPENVDB is set. Or do I have to built openvdb with python from scratch?
